# How to make tree output only directories?

Tags: files, directory, opensource-projects

150 directories I can handle but 900 files is too many for a review. I've no manual entry for `tree` so maybe I can ask you if you know how to output only directories since files get too detailed?

```
.
├── agreement.htm
├── appengine_admin
│   ├── admin_forms.py
│   ├── admin_forms.pyc
│   ├── admin_settings.py
│   ├── admin_settings.pyc
│   ├── admin_widgets.py
│   ├── admin_widgets.pyc
│   ├── authorized.py
│   ├── authorized.pyc
│   ├── db_extensions.py
│   ├── encoding.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __init__.pyc
│   ├── media
│   │   ├── images
│   │   │   ├── default-bg.gif
│   │   │   ├── icon_calendar.gif
│   │   │   ├── icon_clock.gif
│   │   │   ├── nav-bg.gif
│   │   │   └── sidebar-li.png
│   │   ├── js
│   │   │   ├── calendar.js
│   │   │   ├── core.js
│   │   │   └── DateTimeShortcuts.js
│   │   └── style.css
│   ├── model_register.py
│   ├── model_register.pyc
│   ├── templates
│   │   ├── 404.html
│   │   ├── 500.html
│   │   ├── admin_base.html
│   │   ├── index.html
│   │   ├── model_item_edit.html
│   │   └── model_item_list.html
│   ├── utils.py
│   ├── utils.pyc
│   ├── views.py
│   └── views.pyc
├── appengine_config.py
├── appengine_config.py.bak
├── appengine_config.pyc
├── app.yaml
├── br.py
├── br.py.bak
├── br.py.old
├── captcha.py
├── captcha.pyc
├── common
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __init__.pyc
│   ├── templatefilters.py
│   └── templatefilters.pyc
├── conf
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __init__.pyc
│   ├── locale
│   │   ├── ar
│   │   │   └── LC_MESSAGES
│   │   │       ├── django.mo
│   │   │       └── django.po
│   │   ├── bg
│   │   │   └── LC_MESSAGES
│   │   │       ├── django.mo
│   │   │       └── django.po
│   │   ├── en
│   │   │   └── LC_MESSAGES
│   │   │       ├── django.mo
│   │   │       └── django.po
│   │   ├── es
│   │   │   └── LC_MESSAGES
│   │   │       ├── django.mo
│   │   │       └── django.po
│   │   ├── fi
│   │   │   └── LC_MESSAGES
│   │   │       ├── django.mo
│   │   │       └── django.po
│   │   ├── fr
│   │   │   └── LC_MESSAGES
│   │   │       ├── django.mo
│   │   │       ├── django.po
│   │   │       └── django.po~
│   │   ├── ja
│   │   │   └── LC_MESSAGES
│   │   │       ├── django.mo
│   │   │       └── django.po
│   │   ├── pt
│   │   │   └── LC_MESSAGES
│   │   │       ├── django.mo
│   │   │       ├── django.po
│   │   │       └── django.po~
│   │   ├── ro
│   │   │   └── LC_MESSAGES
│   │   │       ├── django.mo
│   │   │       └── django.po
│   │   ├── ru
│   │   │   └── LC_MESSAGES
│   │   │       ├── django.mo
│   │   │       └── django.po
│   │   ├── sq
│   │   │   └── LC_MESSAGES
│   │   │       ├── django.mo
│   │   │       └── django.po
│   │   ├── sv
│   │   │   └── LC_MESSAGES
│   │   │       ├── django.mo
│   │   │       └── django.po
│   │   ├── tl
│   │   │   └── LC_MESSAGES
│   │   │       ├── django.mo
│   │   │       └── django.po
│   │   ├── tr
│   │   │   └── LC_MESSAGES
│   │   │       ├── django.mo
│   │   │       └── django.po
│   │   └── zh
│   │       └── LC_MESSAGES
│   │           ├── django.mo
│   │           └── django.po
│   └── settings.py
├── credit
│   └── credit.html
├── cron.yaml
├── demjson.py
├── demjson.pyc
├── errorpages.py
├── facebookapi.py
├── facebookapi.py.bak
├── facebookapi.pyc
├── facebookconf.py
├── facebookconf.pyc
├── geo
│   ├── geocell.py
│   ├── geocell.pyc
│   ├── geocell_test.py
│   ├── geomath.py
│   ├── geomath.pyc
│   ├── geomath_test.py
│   ├── geomodel.py
│   ├── geomodel.pyc
│   ├── geotypes.py
│   ├── geotypes.pyc
│   ├── geotypes_test.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __init__.pyc
│   ├── test_coverage.sh
│   ├── util.py
│   ├── util.pyc
│   └── util_test.py
├── help.html
├── i18n.py
├── i18n.py.bak
├── i18n.pyc
├── index.yaml
├── __init__.py
├── in.old.py
├── in.old.py.bak
├── in.py
├── in.py.bak
├── in.tidy.py
├── javascript.py
├── js
│   ├── a.css
│   ├── b.css
│   ├── c.css
│   ├── d.css
│   ├── listcss.css
│   ├── load.js
│   ├── main.css
│   └── mycss.css
├── jsmin.py
├── json.py
├── json.pyc
├── listfiles.py
├── login_required.py
├── login_required.py.bak
├── mailman.py
├── main.old.py
├── main.py
├── main.py.bak
├── main.pyc
├── mapreduce
│   ├── base_handler.py
│   ├── base_handler.py.bak
│   ├── context.py
│   ├── context.py.bak
│   ├── control.py
│   ├── control.py.bak
│   ├── errors.py
│   ├── errors.py.bak
│   ├── handlers.py
│   ├── handlers.py.bak
│   ├── hooks.py
│   ├── hooks.py.bak
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __init__.py.bak
│   ├── __init__.pyc
│   ├── input_readers.py
│   ├── input_readers.py.bak
│   ├── lib
│   │   ├── blobstore
│   │   ├── files
│   │   │   ├── blobstore.py
│   │   │   ├── crc32c.py
│   │   │   ├── file.py
│   │   │   ├── file_service_pb.py
│   │   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   │   ├── records.py
│   │   │   └── testutil.py
│   │   ├── graphy
│   │   │   ├── backends
│   │   │   │   ├── google_chart_api
│   │   │   │   │   ├── encoders.py
│   │   │   │   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   │   │   │   └── util.py
│   │   │   │   └── __init__.py
│   │   │   ├── bar_chart.py
│   │   │   ├── common.py
│   │   │   ├── formatters.py
│   │   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   │   ├── line_chart.py
│   │   │   ├── pie_chart.py
│   │   │   ├── README
│   │   │   └── util.py
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── key_range
│   │   │   └── __init__.py
│   │   ├── pipeline
│   │   │   ├── common.py
│   │   │   ├── handlers.py
│   │   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   │   ├── models.py
│   │   │   ├── pipeline.py
│   │   │   ├── simplejson
│   │   │   │   ├── decoder.py
│   │   │   │   ├── encoder.py
│   │   │   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   │   │   ├── ordered_dict.py
│   │   │   │   ├── scanner.py
│   │   │   │   └── tool.py
│   │   │   ├── testutil.py
│   │   │   ├── ui
│   │   │   │   ├── common.css
│   │   │   │   ├── common.js
│   │   │   │   ├── images
│   │   │   │   │   ├── treeview-black.gif
│   │   │   │   │   ├── treeview-black-line.gif
│   │   │   │   │   ├── treeview-default.gif
│   │   │   │   │   └── treeview-default-line.gif
│   │   │   │   ├── jquery-1.4.2.min.js
│   │   │   │   ├── jquery.ba-hashchange.min.js
│   │   │   │   ├── jquery.cookie.js
│   │   │   │   ├── jquery.json.min.js
│   │   │   │   ├── jquery.timeago.js
│   │   │   │   ├── jquery.treeview.css
│   │   │   │   ├── jquery.treeview.min.js
│   │   │   │   ├── status.css
│   │   │   │   ├── status.html
│   │   │   │   └── status.js
│   │   │   └── util.py
│   │   └── simplejson
│   │       ├── decoder.py
│   │       ├── encoder.py
│   │       ├── __init__.py
│   │       ├── README
│   │       └── scanner.py
│   ├── main.py
│   ├── main.py.bak
│   ├── mapper_pipeline.py
│   ├── mapper_pipeline.py.bak
│   ├── mapreduce_pipeline.py
│   ├── mapreduce_pipeline.py.bak
│   ├── model.py
│   ├── model.py.bak
│   ├── namespace_range.py
│   ├── namespace_range.py.bak
│   ├── operation
│   │   ├── base.py
│   │   ├── base.pyc
│   │   ├── counters.py
│   │   ├── counters.pyc
│   │   ├── db.py
│   │   ├── db.pyc
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── __init__.pyc
│   ├── output_writers.py
│   ├── output_writers.py.bak
│   ├── quota.py
│   ├── quota.py.bak
│   ├── shuffler.py
│   ├── shuffler.py.bak
│   ├── static
│   │   ├── base.css
│   │   ├── detail.html
│   │   ├── jquery-1.4.2.min.js
│   │   ├── overview.html
│   │   └── status.js
│   ├── status.py
│   ├── status.py.bak
│   ├── test_support.py
│   ├── test_support.py.bak
│   ├── util.py
│   └── util.py.bak
├── mapreduce.yaml
├── market
│   ├── categories.html
│   ├── credit.html
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── market_ad_detail.html
│   ├── market_ad_edit.html
│   ├── market_ad_newpasswd.html
│   ├── market_ad_pay.html
│   ├── market_ad_preview.html
│   ├── market_ad_remove.html
│   ├── market_ad_renew.html
│   ├── market_detail.html
│   ├── market_full.html
│   ├── market_list.html
│   ├── market_mailc2c.html
│   ├── market_search.html
│   ├── market_usersads_list.html
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── nav.html
│   └── publish.html
├── onlinedebug
│   ├── codeinput.html
│   └── onlinedebug.py
├── paginator.py
├── paginator.pyc
├── PythonTidy-1.20.py
├── PythonTidy-1.20.py.bak
├── reindent.py
├── remote_api.py
├── reports.py
├── settings.py
├── settings.pyc
├── static
│   ├── base.css
│   ├── button-background.gif
│   ├── cancel.png
│   ├── challenge
│   ├── channel.html
│   ├── codebase
│   │   ├── dhtmlxcommon.js
│   │   ├── dhtmlxtree.css
│   │   ├── dhtmlxtree.js
│   │   └── imgs
│   │       ├── blank.gif
│   │       ├── but_cut.gif
│   │       ├── folderClosed.gif
│   │       ├── folderOpen.gif
│   │       ├── iconCheckAll.gif
│   │       ├── iconCheckDis.gif
│   │       ├── iconCheckGray.gif
│   │       ├── iconUncheckAll.gif
│   │       ├── iconUncheckDis.gif
│   │       ├── leaf.gif
│   │       ├── line1.gif
│   │       ├── line1_rtl.gif
│   │       ├── line2.gif
│   │       ├── line2_rtl.gif
│   │       ├── line3.gif
│   │       ├── line3_rtl.gif
│   │       ├── line4.gif
│   │       ├── line4_rtl.gif
│   │       ├── line.gif
│   │       ├── lock.gif
│   │       ├── minus2.gif
│   │       ├── minus2_rtl.gif
│   │       ├── minus3.gif
│   │       ├── minus3_rtl.gif
│   │       ├── minus4.gif
│   │       ├── minus4_rtl.gif
│   │       ├── minus5.gif
│   │       ├── minus5_rtl.gif
│   │       ├── minus_ar.gif
│   │       ├── minus.gif
│   │       ├── plus2.gif
│   │       ├── plus2_rtl.gif
│   │       ├── plus3.gif
│   │       ├── plus3_rtl.gif
│   │       ├── plus4.gif
│   │       ├── plus4_rtl.gif
│   │       ├── plus5.gif
│   │       ├── plus5_rtl.gif
│   │       ├── plus_ar.gif
│   │       ├── plus.gif
│   │       ├── radio_off.gif
│   │       ├── radio_on.gif
│   │       └── Thumbs.db
│   ├── comet-helper.js
│   ├── comet.js
│   ├── common.js
│   ├── credit.html
│   ├── crossajax.html
│   ├── css
│   │   ├── 960.css
│   │   ├── business.css
│   │   ├── montao.css
│   │   ├── openid.css
│   │   ├── reset.css
│   │   ├── style.css
│   │   ├── text.css
│   │   ├── uni-form.css
│   │   └── uni-form-generic.css
│   ├── extinfowindow.js
│   ├── failure.png
│   ├── favicon.ico
│   ├── favindex.ico
│   ├── fbjs.js
│   ├── feedicon.gif
│   ├── file.html
│   ├── for_sale_files
│   │   ├── 1x1_pages_li_c6_apuk_qh5569.gif
│   │   ├── all_pages.js
│   │   ├── arrays_v2.js
│   │   ├── bevakning_mini.gif
│   │   ├── common_in.css
│   │   ├── common.js
│   │   ├── ga.js
│   │   ├── generic.css
│   │   ├── jquery-1.js
│   │   ├── list.css
│   │   ├── searchbox.js
│   │   ├── thumb_extra_left_bottom.gif
│   │   ├── thumb_extra_right_bottom.gif
│   │   ├── thumb_extra_right_top.gif
│   │   ├── thumb_left_top.gif
│   │   ├── thumb_single_left_bottom.gif
│   │   ├── thumb_single_right_bottom.gif
│   │   ├── thumb_single_right_top.gif
│   │   ├── transparent.gif
│   │   └── xtcore.js
│   ├── frames.html
│   ├── ga.js
│   ├── geo.html
│   ├── googleb4b3b9748fe57cbf.html
│   ├── greybox.js
│   ├── iframe.js
│   ├── images
│   │   ├── 1.jpg
│   │   ├── 2.jpg
│   │   ├── 3.jpg
│   │   ├── dl.jpg
│   │   ├── go.jpg
│   │   ├── openid-providers-en.png
│   │   ├── openid-providers-ru.png
│   │   ├── openid-providers-uk.png
│   │   ├── p_debug1.JPG
│   │   ├── p_debug2.JPG
│   │   ├── p_debug3_1.JPG
│   │   ├── p_debug3_2.JPG
│   │   ├── p_debug3.JPG
│   │   ├── p_listfiles.JPG
│   │   ├── preview.jpg
│   │   ├── Thumbs.db
│   │   └── view.jpg
│   ├── images.large
│   │   ├── aol.gif
│   │   ├── facebook.gif
│   │   ├── google.gif
│   │   ├── myopenid.gif
│   │   ├── openid.gif
│   │   ├── rambler.gif
│   │   ├── verisign.gif
│   │   ├── yahoo.gif
│   │   └── yandex.gif
│   ├── images.small
│   │   ├── aol.ico
│   │   ├── aol.ico.gif
│   │   ├── aol.ico.png
│   │   ├── blogger.ico
│   │   ├── blogger.ico.gif
│   │   ├── blogger.ico.png
│   │   ├── claimid.ico
│   │   ├── claimid.ico.gif
│   │   ├── claimid.ico.png
│   │   ├── clickpass.ico
│   │   ├── clickpass.ico.gif
│   │   ├── clickpass.ico.png
│   │   ├── facebook.ico
│   │   ├── facebook.ico.gif
│   │   ├── facebook.ico.png
│   │   ├── flickr.ico
│   │   ├── flickr.ico.gif
│   │   ├── flickr.ico.png
│   │   ├── google.ico
│   │   ├── google.ico.gif
│   │   ├── google.ico.png
│   │   ├── google_profile.ico
│   │   ├── google_profile.ico.gif
│   │   ├── google_profile.ico.png
│   │   ├── launchpad.ico
│   │   ├── launchpad.ico.gif
│   │   ├── launchpad.ico.png
│   │   ├── linkedin.ico
│   │   ├── linkedin.ico.gif
│   │   ├── linkedin.ico.png
│   │   ├── livejournal.ico
│   │   ├── livejournal.ico.gif
│   │   ├── livejournal.ico.png
│   │   ├── myopenid.ico
│   │   ├── myopenid.ico.gif
│   │   ├── myopenid.ico.png
│   │   ├── openid.ico
│   │   ├── openid.ico.gif
│   │   ├── openid.ico.png
│   │   ├── rambler.ico
│   │   ├── rambler.ico.gif
│   │   ├── rambler.ico.png
│   │   ├── technorati.ico
│   │   ├── technorati.ico.gif
│   │   ├── technorati.ico.png
│   │   ├── twitter.ico
│   │   ├── twitter.ico.gif
│   │   ├── twitter.ico.png
│   │   ├── verisign.ico
│   │   ├── verisign.ico.gif
│   │   ├── verisign.ico.png
│   │   ├── vidoop.ico
│   │   ├── vidoop.ico.gif
│   │   ├── vidoop.ico.png
│   │   ├── wordpress.ico
│   │   ├── wordpress.ico.gif
│   │   ├── wordpress.ico.png
│   │   ├── yahoo.ico
│   │   ├── yahoo.ico.gif
│   │   ├── yahoo.ico.png
│   │   ├── yandex.ico
│   │   ├── yandex.ico.gif
│   │   └── yandex.ico.png
│   ├── img
│   │   ├── anuncio.gif
│   │   ├── facebook.gif
│   │   ├── facebook.png
│   │   ├── favicon.ico
│   │   ├── flerabildericon1.gif
│   │   ├── gratis.gif
│   │   ├── kamera.gif
│   │   ├── kool_business.png
│   │   ├── logo.gif
│   │   ├── mail.gif
│   │   ├── marketlogo.gif
│   │   ├── montao.gif
│   │   ├── montao_small.gif
│   │   ├── monton.gif
│   │   ├── sign-in-with-twitter-d.png
│   │   ├── sign-in-with-twitter-d-sm.png
│   │   ├── sign-in-with-twitter-l.png
│   │   ├── sign-in-with-twitter-l-sm.png
│   │   ├── tele.gif
│   │   ├── thumb_left_top.gif
│   │   ├── thumb_single_left_bottom.gif
│   │   ├── thumb_single_right_bottom.gif
│   │   ├── thumb_single_right_top.gif
│   │   └── twittericon.png
│   ├── jquery-1.js
│   ├── js
│   │   ├── jquery-1.2.6.min.js
│   │   ├── openid-jquery-en.js
│   │   ├── openid-jquery.js
│   │   ├── openid-jquery-ru.js
│   │   └── openid-jquery-uk.js
│   ├── json2.js
│   ├── labeledmarker.js
│   ├── listfileshelp.html
│   ├── login.js
│   ├── main.js
│   ├── mootools-1.js
│   ├── myfbjs2.js
│   ├── myfbjs3.js
│   ├── myfbjs.js
│   ├── obrigado.txt
│   ├── onlinedebughelp.html
│   ├── openid-icon.png
│   ├── openid-logo.png
│   ├── orbited.js
│   ├── plugin.js
│   ├── plugin_management.html
│   ├── plugin_management.js
│   ├── privacy.html
│   ├── recaptcha.js
│   ├── robots.txt
│   ├── round_bottom_left.png
│   ├── round_bottom_right.png
│   ├── round_top_left.png
│   ├── round_top_right.png
│   ├── search.html
│   ├── selectuser.js
│   ├── success.png
│   ├── terms.html
│   ├── Thumbs.db
│   ├── Transform.xls
│   ├── transparentpixel.gif
│   ├── tree.html
│   ├── wz_dragdrop.js
│   ├── xd_receiver.htm
│   ├── xd_receiver.html
│   └── yui
│       ├── assets
│       │   ├── bg_hd.gif
│       │   ├── dpSyntaxHighlighter.css
│       │   ├── dpSyntaxHighlighter.js
│       │   ├── example-hd-bg.gif
│       │   ├── Thumbs.db
│       │   ├── title_h_bg.gif
│       │   ├── yui-candy.jpg
│       │   ├── yui.css
│       │   ├── yuiDistribution.css
```

...

```
153 directories, 890 files
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why did this question got downvoted so much?

Comment: Maybe it's becuase the answer is just the manpage

Answer (score 152, accepted):

`tree` man page says:

> ```
>    -d     List directories only.
> ```

So the output of `tree -d YOUR_TARGET_FOLDER` looks like:

```
├── appengine_admin
│   ├── media
│   │   ├── images
│   │   └── js
│   └── templates
├── common
├── conf
│   └── locale
│       ├── ar
│       │   └── LC_MESSAGES
│       ├── bg
│       │   └── LC_MESSAGES
│       ├── en
│       │   └── LC_MESSAGES
│       ├── es
│       │   └── LC_MESSAGES
│       ├── fi
│       │   └── LC_MESSAGES
│       ├── fr
│       │   └── LC_MESSAGES
│       ├── ja
│       │   └── LC_MESSAGES
│       ├── pt
│       │   └── LC_MESSAGES
│       ├── ro
│       │   └── LC_MESSAGES
│       ├── ru
│       │   └── LC_MESSAGES
│       ├── sq
│       │   └── LC_MESSAGES
│       ├── sv
│       │   └── LC_MESSAGES
│       ├── tl
│       │   └── LC_MESSAGES
│       ├── tr
│       │   └── LC_MESSAGES
│       └── zh
│           └── LC_MESSAGES
├── credit
├── geo
├── js
├── mapreduce
│   ├── lib
│   │   ├── blobstore
│   │   ├── files
│   │   ├── graphy
│   │   │   └── backends
│   │   ├── key_range
│   │   ├── pipeline
│   │   │   ├── simplejson
│   │   │   └── ui
│   │   │       └── images
│   │   └── simplejson
│   ├── operation
│   └── static
├── market
├── onlinedebug
├── static
│   ├── challenge
│   ├── codebase
│   │   └── imgs
│   ├── css
│   ├── for_sale_files
│   ├── images
│   ├── images.large
│   ├── images.small
│   ├── img
│   ├── jquery-1.js
│   ├── js
│   └── yui
│       ├── assets
```

Comment: Man page for what?

Comment: @KevinM: man page of `tree`, I suppose the OP is talking about this little application, not installed by default on my system, but available for installation.

Comment: you dont really need to print all your tree... the question is self explanatory

Answer (score 18):

To control the depth of the tree use the `-L` option.

`tree -d -L 2 .`

Answer (score 15):

If you're looking for just a simple list of directories in this directory, then you could try

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d
```

The `1` following maxdepth indicates how many levels of recursion you want. If you're looking for all directories(regardless of depth), then try

```
find . -type d
```

Comment: This is worth mentioning it, it's just a matter of how you'd like the output to look.

Comment: This is great, except that it shows hidden directories (e.g. `.git`) which sometimes is not desired because the output is again too large. Perhaps there's an option for that too but didn't see it yet on the man page.